# Do I need to evconnlistener_disable() before fork()?

Tags: c, linux, fork, libevent

I am developing a server app with libevent now.

The server sometimes needs to exec some external command (i.e.  `fork()` then `exec()`). My concern is that, right after `fork()`, both the parent and the child might be effectively listening, and the child may have a chance to 'accept' a new incoming connection before it `exec()`s, this could cause the parent (the server app) to lose an incoming request.

Do I need to `evconnlistener_disable()` before `fork()` and `evconnlistener_enable()` after `fork()`?

Comment: How does libevent listen? Does it use a separate thread? Does it have an event loop function which you must call to process events?

Comment: Oh, you remind me. I use libevent in classic way, that is single-threaded, all callbacks come from the event loop. So I don't need to worry about this, libevent doesn't 'accept' some thing until control flow back to the event loop. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, depending on what exactly you're aiming for. You can use wait() on the parent to effectively pause it until the child has finished. Or immediately close the listener file descriptor in the child. Or, if you're only worried about incoming requests during an exec(), you can set the close-on-exec flag on the file descriptor (FD_CLOEXEC).

I would have thought that disabling the listener before fork() and then re-enabling it would re-enable it for the child, too.

Comment: Oh, I should set the  FD_CLOEXEC flag, I missed, thank you. I guess my concern doesn't happen, as 'user253751' mentioned in question comment.